# Is it possible to restrict iOS app to single city?

Tags: ios

I am developing a social nightlife app for a single city.  We obviously dont want users from other cities downloading the app and "skewing" the data.  Is it possible to restrict users of the app to a certain city?

Thanks,

Comment: I dont think you can limit downloads, but just grab the user coordinates on the first load, and dont show anything if theyre not in the right area.

Comment: Good call. Is there a way to define a range of coordinates? (so that isf someone falls outside the range you popup a message or something?)

Comment: Yeah look into mkcoordinateregions

Comment: I could easily imagine someone planning a visit to a city being interested in a social nightlife app for it. Even if it were possible, I can't see it being a good idea to restrict it. Just make the name and description clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask for the user's location and if they grant permission to access their location and it's outside of whatever radius you choose, you can do whatever you want.  However, Apple might reject it if they don't like your user experience.  What might be a better approach is to let everyone use the app, but then ignore data generated from outside your city.

Also, what if someone from your city is away but still wants to access your app?  Or someone is planning on moving to your city?  If your app really has content focused on your city why the concern that hordes of people outside the city are going to skew your data?  I would think that anyone using your app is going to be interested in or connected to your city in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the download of an app to a particular city, but you CAN restrict it's operation programmatically.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html for location related services available in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

You could access location services and see if the device is within the city boundary. If they are not, you could either ignore their data or just force close the application.

Comment: Is this spelled out in the documentation? I'm wondering what the syntax might look like to define a city boundary.

Comment: You cannot force close an iOS app as per Apple's guidelines.